# spring injecting groovy bean: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, groovy

Let me start with the root cause of the exception I'm getting,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15 implementing com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter,com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsAccumulator] to required type [com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter] for property 'statisticsReporter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:440) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
```

which is really weird since it is basically saying that it cannot convert an object which implements `StatisticsReporter` and something else to the type `StatisticsReporter`.

This happened when injecting a groovy class as a Spring bean:

```
<lang:groovy id="clientsDetailsManager" script-source="classpath:com/company/product/security/CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager.groovy">
    <lang:property name="configuration" ref="confAuthentication"/>
    <lang:property name="statisticsReporter" ref="statisticsReporter"/>
</lang:groovy>
```

Since I'm by far more confortable with Java, I tried the same bean injection but using a java class, and it worked perfectly ok. But I need to make it work in groovy. Any ideas about what the problem is would be highly appreciated.

Some code excerpts (if it makes sense that I add anything else just tell me):

beans in java

```
<bean id="statisticsReporter" factory-bean="statisticsAdministrator" factory-method="getStatisticsReporter"/>

<bean id="clientsDetailsManager" class="com.company.product.security.CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager">
    <constructor-arg name="configuration" ref="confAuthentication"/>
    <constructor-arg name="statisticsReporter" ref="statisticsReporter"/>
</bean>
```

Java class for the object I'm injecting in the bean (only constructors):

```
public class CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager extends ClientDetailsManager {

    public CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager() {
        super();
    }

    public CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager(Client[] clients, StatisticsReporter statisticsReporter) {
        super(clients, statisticsReporter);
    }

    public CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager(Configuration configuration, StatisticsReporter statisticsReporter) {
        super(configuration, statisticsReporter);
    }    
    ...
}
```

Java class for the parent (only constructors and some variables):

```
public class ClientDetailsManager implements UserDetailsManager {

    protected ConcurrentMap<String, Client> cache;
    protected Configuration                 configuration;
    private StatisticsReporter              statisticsReporter;

    // empty constructor and setters for properties needed when groovy class as spring bean
    public ClientDetailsManager() {
        this.cache = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();     
    }

    public ClientDetailsManager(Configuration configuration, StatisticsReporter statisticsReporter) {
        this.cache = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();     
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.statisticsReporter = statisticsReporter;
    }

    Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void setStatisticsReporter(StatisticsReporter statisticsReporter) {
        this.statisticsReporter = statisticsReporter;
    }

    /** Only for testing purposes. */
    public ClientDetailsManager(Client[] clients, StatisticsReporter statisticsReporter) {
        this.cache = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Java class for which it does not find "conversion strategy" when injecting in groovy:

```
public class StatisticsAdministrator extends AbstractAdministrator {
   …
    private StatisticsReporter    statisticsReporter;

    public StatisticsReporter getStatisticsReporter() {
        return statisticsReporter;
    }

}
```

For my trials, I've used a groovy version of `CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager` which content was exactly the java class.

And finally, the beginning of the stacktrace, although I don't think it is relevant:

> 2015-11-18 15:09:15,344 ERROR [main] Starter - Error creating bean
>   with name 'ocsHttpConnectorFactoryAdministrator' defined in class path
>   resource [beans/nodes.ocs.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'exporter' while setting bean property 'jmxBeanExporter'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'exporter' defined in class path
>   resource [beans/jmx.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'muticastClusterEngine' while setting bean property 'broadcaster';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'muticastClusterEngine' defined in class path
>   resource [beans/cluster.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'clientsDetailsManager' while setting constructor argument; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'clientsDetailsManager':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scriptedObject.clientsDetailsManager':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15 implementing
>   com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter,com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsAccumulator'
>   to required type 'com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter'
>   for property 'statisticsReporter'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15 implementing
>   com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter,com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsAccumulator]
>   to required type [com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter]
>   for property 'statisticsReporter': no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'ocsHttpConnectorFactoryAdministrator' defined
>   in class path resource [beans/nodes.ocs.xml]: Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'exporter' while setting bean property 'jmxBeanExporter';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'exporter' defined in class path resource
>   [beans/jmx.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'muticastClusterEngine' while setting bean property 'broadcaster';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'muticastClusterEngine' defined in class path
>   resource [beans/cluster.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'clientsDetailsManager' while setting constructor argument; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'clientsDetailsManager':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scriptedObject.clientsDetailsManager':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15 implementing
>   com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter,com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsAccumulator'
>   to required type 'com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter'
>   for property 'statisticsReporter'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15 implementing
>   com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter,com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsAccumulator]
>   to required type [com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter]
>   for property 'statisticsReporter': no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found …
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15 implementing
>   com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter,com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsAccumulator]
>   to required type [com.company.product.statistics.StatisticsReporter]
>   for property 'statisticsReporter': no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:440)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
>           ... 62 common frames omitted

Many thanks!

Comment: The `CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager` constructor and its call of the `super` constructor don't seem to match; `super(clients, statisticsReporter)` and `(Configuration configuration, StatisticsReporter statisticsReporter)`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @tylerwal. Actually I failed to post one constructor for `CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager` and another one for `ClientDetailsManager`. I'm updating the question. My original intention was to post only the one used in the bean, which has arguments `Configuration` and `StatisticsReporter`. The other is for test purposes.

Comment: Very welcome.  In your groovy bean, you don't have the line `<bean id="statisticsReporter" ...` - have you tried with this? The `statisticsReporter` bean still needs to be created for the injection to occur.

Comment: Yes @tylerwal, I've tried it. I didn't post it, but in my trials with groovy everything is the same as in Java, in the xml I just comment the Java bean and uncomment the groovy. It is very weird. It must be something very silly that I'm doing, but I've spent quite a few hours and didn't figure it out. I have other groovy beans working, the only difference is that this `CaseInsensitiveClientDetailsManager` groovy extends the Java class `ClientDetailsManager`. I mean, other groovy beans working are just pure groovy. Thanks again.